# Netty - Second packet is ignored

Tags: java, sockets, networking, netty, nio

If I send two packets immediately, the second packet is usually ignored by the client. There's some cases in which it will pick it up, but it's usually just like it was never sent to begin with. I've done all the debugging and it seems like the server is definitely sending it, but the client never has a clue.

I'm using a `ByteBuf` which is the new version of a `ChannelBuffer` in Netty 4.

Here's how I'm sending the information over the network:

```
getChannel().writeAndFlush(buffer.retain());
```

Now the strange part is, nothing is getting mixed up if I send these together. The original packet data is all together like it should be, no problems.

The second packet just doesn't come through at all.

So, for example.

```
ByteBuf bufferA = Unpooled.buffer();
ByteBuf bufferB = Unpooled.buffer();
bufferA.writeInt(1);
bufferB.writeInt(2);
send(bufferA);
send(bufferB);
```

The client will only read bufferA, and completely ignore bufferB, won't even register a single byte of it.

If i space these out using Thread.sleep, the client loads them fine.

Not sure what to do?

Server and Client are both using netty.

EDIT: I'm currently using a "Cheat" fix that runs a scheduled executor for this case (Where I need to send two packets one after another) but this doesn't at all fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to send the same buffer two times ? In this case you need to call duplicate() on it first as otherwise it will share the same readerIndex and writerIndex which will be adjusted when a ByteBuf is written to the underlying socket.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case: `[OGSERVER]: Debug 1
[OGSERVER]: Packet with an id of 0 was constructed.
[OGSERVER]: The packet was 16 bytes long.
[OGSERVER]: The packet type was TCP
[OGSERVER]: ============================================================
[OGSERVER]: Debug 2
[OGSERVER]: Packet with an id of 1 was constructed.
[OGSERVER]: The packet was 8 bytes long.
[OGSERVER]: The packet type was TCP
[OGSERVER]: ============================================================`

Which shows the different buffers being sent.

Comment: The clients however, only prints this: `[TCP]Packet opcode with id of 0 was received. Length: 16` which shows it only ever acknowledges the first buffer? If the buffer was being sent twice, it would say so.

Comment: Without the more detail its hard to say. Can you share your full code ?